# WPF Commands - Invocation of Handlers

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am a beginner to WPF. I read about commands , when do the handlers for the command get triggered, because i attached a Coomand for the button and a menu , the handler is invoked either the menu or the button is clicked. Is it possible to invoke the handler on double clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood the query properly then you are trying to attach the same command to both a button and a menu.Then i should say the command will get executed for both the cases.

Check the following links.

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFCommandingTheBasic.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfCommandPatternApplied.aspx

In the case of **double click** Check the link below

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Invoking_a_Command_on_a_Double_Click_or_other_Mouse_Gesture.aspx

Also go through Marlon Grech's [attached command behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) .It will give you a handfull of added functionalities

This will get you started for sure.Hope it helps